# Migrating from Titan to DataStax Enterprise Graph

Tags: datastax, titan, datastax-enterprise-graph

I'm migrating from Titan to Datastax. I have a graph with around 50 million nodes that is composed in Persons, Addresses, Phones, etc

I want to calculate a Person node connections (how many persons have the same phone, addresses, etc).

In Titan I wrote a Hadoop job that go over al the person nodes an the I could write a gremlin script to see how many persons have the same phone for this particular node

So as an input properties I have:

```
titan.hadoop.input.format=com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.formats.hbase.TitanHBaseInputFormat
titan.hadoop.input.conf.storage.backend=hbase
```

For query filter I query only the person nodes

```
titan.hadoop.graph.input.vertex-query-filter=v.query().has('type',Compare.EQUAL,'person')
```

And to run a script I use

```
titan.hadoop.output.conf.script-file=scripts/calculate.groovy
```

this will calculate for every node the number of shared phones connection that the person has.

```
object.phone_shared= object.as('x').out('person_phones').in('person_phones').except('x').count()
```

Is there a way to write this kind of scripts in Datastax to go over the persons nodes. I see that Datastax uses Spark analytics to count the nodes for example,

https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/northwindDemoGraphSnapshot.html

but I didn't found any more documentation on how to run custom scripts using analytics

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer happens to be on the page you linked. It seems like it might just be a little easier than you are used to with Titan. The key is on step 8 where you configure the Traversal to use the preconfigured OLAP/Analytics TraversalSource, which is named `a` (for Analytics).

> 8. Alias the traversal to the Northwind analytics OLAP traversal source
>      a. Alias g to the OLAP traversal source for one-off analytic queries:
>
> `gremlin> :remote config alias g northwind.a`

This basically says..
 "When I execute a Traversal on TraversalSource `g`, I want it to be aliased to `northwind.a` on the server".

Once you do that, all Traversals of `g` will be executed using `northwind.a` and thus the Spark analytics engine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got that part with the OLAP traversal. I need two things. One is to calculate the shared connection and the other on is to export it into a file. Can you provide me a simple example on how do I calculate the shared connections with analytics. Thanks

Comment: I've made this script: g.V().hasLabel('person').has('id',8438957).match(             __.as("a").out('has_address').in('has_address').count().as('address_count'),
    __.as("a").out('has_phone').in('has_phone').count().as('phone_count'),
              __.as("a").out('has_vin').in('has_vin').count().as('vin_count'), 
              __.as("a").out('has_dl').in('has_dl').count().as('dl_count'), 
              __.as("a").values("id").as("person_id"),   
              ).select("person_id","address_count", "phone_count", "dl_count", "vin_count")
But this one is not working in alaytics

Comment: What is the error you are receiving and does this work in OLTP mode?

Comment: @jlacefie this is the error that I have for this query 
g.V().hasLabel('person').match(         __.as("a").out('has_address').in('has_address').count().as('address_count'))
              .select("person_id","address_count")
**Local traversals may not traverse past the local star-graph on GraphComputer: [VertexStep(OUT,[has_address],vertex), VertexStep(IN,[has_address],vertex), CountGlobalStep]**

Comment: @CristiC did you figure it out? i ran into the same issue and wonder if you found a solution yet. thanks!

Comment: HI, you can't use this in the OLAT you need to re-think this query